# Processing - Starting Function and Stopping function

Tags: java, processing

I have this processing app that contains 2 functions. 1st is called loadScreen. 2nd is called mainMenu. When the app initializes, it calls the function "loadScreen();". I set a timer inside this function so that after 5 seconds, it will jump to "mainMenu". The problem is that how do I stop my function and call another function? Is there a "break;" or "stop" function that I can use? Thanks!

```
void loading() {  //Code to load start screen 

if (millis() - time >= wait) {
time = millis();//also update the stored time
image(loadingImage, 0, 0);
}
if (time/1000 == 5) {
time=5000; // Stop here
startMenu();
}
}

void startMenu() {
//Code to load the real game
text("Start", 350, 300);
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post adding the code? This will allow a better answer.

Comment: Tell us something about the platform and the constraints you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `FutureTask` but with multiple threads. Say:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(new Callable<Integer>(){

        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            image(loadingImage, 0, 0);
            return -1;
        }

    });
    Future<Integer> res = exec.submit(task);
    try {
        res.get(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    //waited 5 sec to execute hence coming out
    }
    loadMenu();
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't really understand it. Is it for Processing?

Comment: Processing what? I think we need more contezt on what you're actually trying to achieve. We don't know nothing about platform etc...

Comment: Ok. So this is what the code does. It creates a new thread and asks the thread to to do `image(loadingIamge,0,0)`. It waits for the other thread to execute it for 5 seconds. If it does, all well. If it it doesn;t it stops the thread doing `image(...)` and calls teh second function. Clear?

Comment: u cannot do it from the same thread. Another thread instructs a thread to stop what it is doing and calls the second function